# Audio transfer android and node-webkit

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, webkit

I have been trying to transfer audio files between my android app and my node-webkit app but I'm new to the world of socket.io/nodejs/delivery.js.

Here is my code:

android-code   ERROR-LINE: os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Socket sock;
        try {
            // sock = new Socket("MY_PCs_IP", 1149);
            sock = new Socket("192.168.0.10", 5001);
            System.out.println("Connecting...");
            // sendfile
            File myFile = new File(this.currentSong.getPath());
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            System.out.println("Sended..");
            // RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            in.ready();
            String userInput = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Response from server..." + userInput);

            sock.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

node-webkit-code

```
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(5001),
dl = require('delivery'), //delivery.server
fs  = require('fs');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
delivery = dl.listen(socket);
delivery.on('receive.success',function(file){

    fs.writeFile("music/"+file.name,file.buffer, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('File could not be saved.');
        }else{
            console.log('File saved.');
            addSong("music/"+file.name);

        };
    });
});
});
```

Note: My server side works well it's already tested by a js client

This is the error I am getting:

Android side Error:

```
08-28 14:56:36.180: W/System.err(30510): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken     pipe)
08-28 14:56:36.180: W/System.err(30510):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
08-28 14:56:36.180: W/System.err(30510):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
08-28 14:56:36.180: W/System.err(30510):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
```

So maybe I'm wrong trying to do a bad connection because of protocols.. between a socket and socket.io..?
if any one can help my out I will be pleased. I already looked around but as I said I'm new to this world and I get hazy
basically my question is: What's wrong? and How I accomplish my objective?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Use this instead of delivery, its better..

https://github.com/vote539/socketio-file-upload

Comment: var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
    var SocketIOFileUpload = require("socketio-file-upload");
    io.on("connection", function(socket){
        var uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload();
        uploader.dir = "/musica";
        uploader.listen(socket);
    });
this is what I tried.. still fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.SocketIOClient
there is some problems with this library and socket.io but it it's solved by using this dependency on node-webkit

"socket.io": "~0.9",

also need to read file->base64 codification-> then emit the string on the server side must do this:

```
socket.on('finishFileTransfer',function(){
    fs.writeFile("music/"+fileName,new Buffer(file,'base64'), function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('File could not be saved.');
        }else{
            console.log('File saved.');
            addSong("musica/"+fileName);
        }
        file = "";
        fileName = null;

    });
});
```